# How can I use autonumbers and variables through pyodbc for access?

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I plan to create a database for a project that I'm working on for school, it's a system where staff can enter their name then input their holiday dates and this will be displayed on a calender. Administrators will also be able to add holiday restrictions, remove holidays and also add/remove staff members.

I believe I need to use pyodbc to access an MS-Access database. I believe I will need an autonumber through the database to create a **primary key**. I also think I will need to create a variable when the user adds a holiday or type their names in. 
But from what I've tried, these two do not work together.

```py
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=C:\Users\Ollie\Desktop\pyfon\test.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from tracking_sales')
FirstName = input("Enter your first name: ")
Surname = input("Enter your first name: ")
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tracking_sales VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)',
               (FirstName, Surname, 3, 15))
conn.commit()
```

This works but I don't know how to make it work with an auto number. From what I've tried, to make an autonumber work, one of the fields need to be empty. But also, to make a variable work, all of the fields need to be filled in the INSERT part. Please help, thank you :)

Comment: In your INSERT INTO you need to explicitly name your columns (except for your auto number column).  Like `INSERT INTO tracking_sales (FirstName, LastName, column1, column2) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`

Comment: Working, thank you :) @Rene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your INSERT INTO you need to explicitly name your columns (except for your auto number column). Like INSERT INTO tracking_sales (FirstName, LastName, column1, column2) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)